# How to stop 2 sub-containers from expanding

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

I have this container that I want to stop from expanding when populated with data. I want to know how can I achieve this in css. I have here four containers. Main container(black),sub-container(orange), sub-container1(blue), sub-container2(green). Main container has fill-height of screen. I set the Sub-container1 with 85% of the height of main-container and sub-container2 with 15%. I want to stop sub-container1(blue) and sub-container2(green) from expanding more from its height if I put many contents. Can someone help me how I can achieve this in css?

[image]

Comment: You can use overflow-y: auto; and add fixed height or max-height on both containers

Comment: you can easily use `flex` or `grid` to achieve this, it will be good to use `grid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving the sub-containers a `max-height`? Also, what to do you want to happen with the content that doesn't fit? You can give the sub-containers either an `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: hidden;` for subcontainers.